# Can you use mysqli prepared statements and transactions together?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, rollback, execute

All I want to know is if you can use mysqli's `prepare`, `execute`, and `rollback` together?

```
$m = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname);

$m->autocommit(FALSE);
$stmt = $m->prepare("INSERT `table` (`name`,`gender`,`age`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $name, $gender, $age);
$query_ok = $stmt->execute();

$stmt = $m->prepare("INSERT `table` (`name`,`gender`,`age`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $name, $gender, $age);
if ($query_ok) {$query_ok = $stmt->execute();}

if (!$query_ok) {$m->rollback();} else {$m->commit();}
```

Can you do this?  Let's assume that the above code has a loop and or the variables get new data in them.

Comment: What makes you assume you could / couldn't ?

Comment: I have tried it and it's unclear on the results, which is why I am asking.  The PHP documentation doesn't say anything either way if prepare, execute, and rollback work together.  Any one ever try and or get it to work?

Comment: How about a yes or a no for a response?

Comment: I too am trying to figure this out. It is very hard to find an example with this combination.

Comment: It does work.  I had made a mistake in my selection of the mysql engine.  You need to make sure that the innodb engine is selected for what ever table you wish to use rollback on.

Comment: Refer this answer on stackoverflow, you will get quick solution.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270154/how-to-use-prepare-statement-to-insert-data-to-three-different-tables-in-mysqli)

Answer (score 2):

Best way to handle this is with exceptions (as always, darn PHP error/warning stuff). Simply because our `commit()` call may fail too. Note that `finally` is only available in newer PHP versions.

```
<?php

// Transform all errors to exceptions!
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

try {
  $connection = new \mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);
  $connection->autocommit(false);

  $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT `table` (`name`, `gender`, `age`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $name, $gender, $age);
  $stmt->execute();

  // We can simply reuse the prepared statement if it's the same query.
  //$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT `table` (`name`, `gender`, `age`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

  // We can even reuse the bound parameters.
  //$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $name, $gender, $age);

  // Yet it would be better to write it like this:
  /*
  $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT `table` (`name`, `gender`, `age`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("ssissi", $name, $gender, $age, $name, $gender, $age);
   */

  $stmt->execute();
  $connection->commit();
}
catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $exception) {
  $connection->rollback();
  throw $exception;
}
finally {
  isset($stmt) && $stmt->close();
  $connection->autocommit(true);
}
```